# WM_LBUTTONUP not received in WebBrowser WndProc

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, c++builder, twebbrowser

I have overriden the WndProc of `TWebBrowser` to capture mouse clicks as following (quick example):

```
procedure TWebBrowser.WndProc(var AMsg: TMessage);
begin
with AMsg do
  begin
   case WParam of
     WM_LBUTTONDOWN: Text := "DOWN";
     WM_LBUTTONUP:   Text := "UP";
  end;
end;
```

`WM_LBUTTONDOWN` is happening and works fine. But somethings eats the `WM_LBUTTONUP` message and it never happens. The same thing for right and middle button.

Any ideas why there isn't a BUTTONUP message?

Comment: Why are you looking for the `WM_...` values in the `TMessage.WParam` field rather than in the `TMessage.Msg` field? The `WM_...` values are message ID constants, and the `Msg` field carries the ID of the message that is being received.  The `WParam` and `LParam` fields carry *message-specific supplementary values*. `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` has a numeric value of `$0201`, and `WM_LBUTTONUP` is `$0202`. Other messages could be using those same values for their own purposes, but your code wouldn't know the difference since it is ignoring the `Msg` field.

Comment: Perhaps it is a thing with `TWebBrowser` component because if I use Msg field there is nothing there ever. But WParam changes, based on the click, it just doesn't send any message on mouse-up. The actual value which appears in Msg makes no sense it is $0021 and on mouse-up (right button only) it is $0020, but not for the left one. With $0021 I cannot differentiate between left, middle and right button but with WParam I can actually.

Comment: Msg ID $0021 is `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE`, $0020 is `WM_SETCURSOR`. [`WM_MOUSEACTIVATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mouseactivate) carries `WM_LBUTTON...` values in the high-word of the `LParam`, not the `WParam`. However, you CANNOT simply look at `WParam`/`LParam` to differentiate messages, you MUST look at the `Msg` first, THEN look at `WParam`/`LParam` ONLY IF NEEDED AND VALID to do so. Which is not the case in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given up the above `WndProc` method in the end and solved the problem by sinking the `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` events which also give much more control over the process and also allow for many more events than the above, a method described on this link:

https://www.thoughtco.com/url-hyperlink-twebbrowser-document-1058415

Also additional info can be found here:

[IHTMLDocument2 and Internet Explorer 11 changes on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928458/ihtmldocument2-and-internet-explorer-11-changes-on-windows-7)